# Two COUNT to one SELECT

Tags: sql, count

Can you tell me how I can get these two COUNT into one select please?

```
/*Pocet treninku ucast*/
SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
FROM Hraci 
INNER JOIN Ucast_trenink2 ON Ucast_trenink2.ID_hrace_ucast=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Seznam_treninku ON Seznam_treninku.ID_treninku=Ucast_trenink2.ID_treninku_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Seznam_treninku.Kategorie 
WHERE (Ucast='TRUE')AND(Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Datum < '9/1/2014'
GROUP BY Jmeno;
/*Pocet treninku neucast*/
SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
FROM Hraci 
INNER JOIN Ucast_trenink2 ON Ucast_trenink2.ID_hrace_ucast=Hraci.IDHrace 
INNER JOIN Seznam_treninku ON Seznam_treninku.ID_treninku=Ucast_trenink2.ID_treninku_ucast 
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Seznam_treninku.Kategorie 
WHERE (Ucast='FALSE')AND(Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Datum < '9/1/2014'
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you make clear your requirement? what is get 2 count to one select? Do you wish to merge the queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT
    Jmeno,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'False' then 1 end) as count_false,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'True' then 1 end) as count_true
FROM ...
WHERE (Kategorie.IDkategorie = 1) AND Datum >= '1/1/2013' AND Datum < '9/1/2014'
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```